# jspx doctype not getting parsed in websphere application server 7.0.0.11

Tags: java, parsing, jsf, jspx

I have deployed 2 applications with similar software stack. Primarily they use JSF framework. One application works fine. But when I am hitting the login.jspx page of the other application it throws the below error.

```
com.ibm.ws.jsp.JspCoreException: /login.jspx(1,1) /login.jspx(1,1) www.w3.org
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.document.Jsp2Dom.parseToDom(Jsp2Dom.java:570)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.document.Jsp2Dom.getJspDocument(Jsp2Dom.java:193)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.JspTranslator.<init>(JspTranslator.java:73)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.JspTranslatorFactory.createTranslator(JspTranslatorFactory.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.utils.JspTranslatorUtil.translateJsp(JspTranslatorUtil.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.utils.JspTranslatorUtil.translateJspAndCompile(JspTranslatorUtil.java:120)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.translateJsp(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:512)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper._checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:439)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:297)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:147)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:340)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
```

The DOCTYPE is as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

As mentioned earlier, a similar file in the other application just works fine. I have used the same jars for both the applications and deployed on the same WAS7 instance.

Comment: Have you compared strictly both files (your login.jspx vs. the "similar file")?

Comment: Yes, the DOCTYPE is exactly the same in both the files. As per error, it's failing at row 1 and column 1. The control is going into the file if doctype is removed, but it would be treated as plain html, not xhtml, which I need.

Comment: Hum... Sounds to me as if a validation issue of Websphere was differently set up on both applications. Something like DTD Validation.